# How to get Postgres database name at Linux terminal

Tags: postgresql

I need to connect to a single postgres database but I dont know the name of the database. How can I list names of available databases from the Linux terminal ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
psql -l
```

This requires a login but you can use the same credentials as you would for connecting to the target database